# Why does bind fix "failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window' illegal invocation" error?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, function-binding

I'm just curious,

This...

```js
let s = { f: window.fetch };
s.f("https://www.google.com");
```

fails with

> Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation

While this works...

```js
let s = { f: window.fetch.bind(window) }; 
s.f("https://www.google.com");
```

How does the latter fix the issue? Is there any theory behind why it works that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some internal purpose, the `fetch` function must have `this` be the same as `window`. When you create your own object and just assign the fetch function as one of its properties, the fetch function has no access to the `window` object as `this`.

The [`fetch` specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-window) describes things the `window` might be used for. You might be able to make your original code work by setting `no-window`, but I have not tested that.

Comment: Is this documented on ECMA Spec?

Comment: @jeffbRTC `fetch()` is not part of ES. [It's a web spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/)

Comment: @VLAZ My apologies, where can I find it on the web spec you linked?

Comment: @jeffbRTC the entire spec is only about `fetch()`. I'm not sure where in it it would say that requires `window` (or if it even does).

Comment: @VLAZ Okay, I was looking what's this vague internal purpose mentioned on the answer ..

Comment: @jeffbRTC "internal" might be implementation dependent. But I'm not making a claim that's the case. I've not gone through the spec to confirm or deny this.

Comment: @VLAZ I tested on Firefox - `'fetch' called on an object that does not implement interface Window`